# Where can I ask questions about the alt-codes for the Glottal stop sign?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Where can I ask questions about the alt-codes for the Glottal Stop sign?

Just to make it clear: I am giving the text of my question as context, NOT to actually ask it, since that's not how the site's process works.

For context here is the question I want to ask:

> #### How can I type this sign with an alt-code? Other than copying it, I cannot re-produce this with a keyboard.
>
> I've looked at the links below. There's some info there, but not which Alt-code to use:
>
> https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CA%94#English
>
> https://unicode-table.com/en/0294/
>
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glottal_stop_(letter)#Computing_codes
>
> I don't see how to do it. Perhaps I'm overlooking this, perhaps it's staring me in the face.

Comment: The sort of thing you'll find that SE is best for across the whole network is solving problems. In all seriousness, a duckduckgo search brought up the code as the first result, along with the Unicode and an amount of other interesting stuff. You won't find a better service for simply looking things up than your keyboard and the key search terms (which are in your question in this case).

Comment: I've just tried the various search results and none of them work. Second thoughts, I'm with you. I'll be watching to see what the answer is.

Comment: I didn't provide the example question on purpose, because people would start losing their minds and scream it's not the appropiate place. StackExchange is not an openminded kind of place like that. @ARogueAnt. I tried looking it up, but there's NO alt-code to be found. Just some U-code, which doesn't work while typing.

Comment: The tag wiki for recommendation questions has explicit guidance how to ask these type of questions: https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/site-recommendation/info. We scream at questions that don't follow the format suggested in the tag wiki

Comment: @rene well, that's kind of useful info. The kind that the local site 'experts' might give BEFORE screaming and (gleefully?) down voting a thing..... I'm sure that **yóú** don't do that, like never. <3<3<3 Aaand .... also the info that could **pop-up** before each question IS actually asked, especially for those who don't ask a **LOT** of questions... I'm pretty sure the clever people here and site-builders can add a type of <<<"IF  member has low question count, OR many off-topic stuff THEN let a message pop advising about the site-recommendations tag IF not THEN not>>> condition to the site<3

Comment: @GwenKillerby Not everything is presented here are at the askers convenience but I'm glad you found it useful after the fact. I'm sure at your next question the hard to discover tag wiki's  will be visited by you. Do Tweet about your positive experience on Meta. The curators here can use some cheers, given the normal insults thrown at them.

Comment: tweet? well, my comment was intended as half serious, and half ironic. I've read yours as also being ironic too.  Supposing I **do** tweet about it: tweet with what hashtag?

Answer (score 4):

Our Super User site has these questions, the first is the same as yours, the second is an additional helpful one:

- "[Output "LATIN LET­TER SMALL CA­PI­TAL M" with Alt-NumKeypad sequence?](https://superuser.com/questions/1147985/output-latin-letter-small-capital-m-with-alt-numkeypad-sequence)"
- "[bash - wrong key sequence bindings with control+alt+space](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/191527/261962)"

So, Super User accepts this topic; and it's already answered there.

Comment: Hmm, I don't see an answer there. What is the alt-code for this character? Or what is the hexadecimal code for it?

Comment: Follow the second link and substitute your character, it looks like it's 660. https://www.arild-hauge.com/altcodes.htm

Comment: ö is what that gives me both in comments and in a test question here on MSE, so no, not on SE. @Rob

Comment: @LittlePickle. you'll have to comment on that answer there if it doesn't help you. The question **here** is: "**Where** can I ask questions about the alt-codes for the Glottal stop sign?", my answer does answer that question; whether the people there provide answers that work with your setup, or the way you interpret them, is YMMV.

Comment: Good point @Rob Though, if I go away and test it in other places and find that it's just SE that doesn't produce the standard result to that code, then that may warrant a separate question about the whys and wherefores.

Comment: @LittlePickle., These answers may answer your questions: https://superuser.com/q/287451/419485 https://superuser.com/q/64178/419485  https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/42069/40203 https://stackoverflow.com/q/66693043/3648282 - It's *technique*, software used / installed, and Codepage in use.

Comment: ॽˤॽ - nice one @Rob Babelmap in my case now.